# Where do I find the latest Blender release?

Tags: installation

Where do I find the latest Blender release to install and what version should I use?

I'm not sure what OS I have and don't know what 32bit or 64bit is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The latest production-ready version can be found on
>   **www.blender.org** in the downloade page. (Direct link - [blender.org/download](https://www.blender.org/download/))

## Finding the right version

If you are unsure of what version you should use, try the one that the page suggest with a big button. If you are denied to install or start it, go to the list of other versions and see if an archive (.zip / .rar / .7zip example given) version that matches what was recommended from the page. Open the archive and copy the folder that is in it to the desktop or where you like to keep your files. You start blender by launching the executable (same thing as a program) blender and not BlenderPlayer. (if the page recommended a 32bit version a 64bit is unlikely to work)

> If you have come this far. If someone does call you on the phone from a number you don't recognize and offer you support, say that you will call them back and only do that if the number belongs to someone you can trust.

If neither the recommended version or the archive work ask your support for help or computer administrator if needed. (The administrator will probably appreciate that you asked the support first)

If you don't have any support you can try this steps to find what OS you have and try the version for that instead.

1. If you have an interface that is based on typing on your keyboard to enter commands only. Ask the person that installed it or gave it to you for help, otherwise, go to your local computer store and ask for help.
2. Enter mmc.exe in the search bar and if you can launch the program you have windows. Try the different 32bit versions or if it complains and wants a 64bit, try them instead, otherwise test the next step.
3. If you have a  <- Apple Inc. logo in the corner, press it and go to about this mac. If you can do this you have OS X, otherwise, test the next step.
4. Contact the person that did give you your computer and ask for help or go to your local computer store and ask for help, otherwise test the next step.
5. Se if you can find the answer on these pages:

   - [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com)
   - [support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201581)

## Wher to find the latest features/experimental builds

The newest features and build can be found on [builder.blender.org](https://builder.blender.org/download/) and should be considered unstable. Don't save anything with the realizes that you need later because the versions might corrupt the files.

If the version does cause the computer to freeze or crash repeatedly under normal use, go to the builder page and enter the requested information and force a new build for that version if no new have been realized.

If you want one of the current development versions read the [wiki.blender.org](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender) on how to compile blender from the current code.

!!Do not forget to do the checkout or it will not work!!

Comment: A 64bit system can run both 32 and 64bit programs. A 32bit system can only run 32bit apps. If your machine has more than 4GB of ram then you wil most likely be running a 64bit system. Another source of experimental builds is [graphicall.org](http://graphicall.org)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Blender website](https://www.blender.org/)

Click on downloand and a new page opens, as seen below

[image]

Before you click on the download button. Click the small arrow button pointing downwards (macOS, linux, other version) as marked in red. You can find various Operating systems. Select the correct Operating system and click on it.